# How do i pass radio button value to controller?

Tags: angularjs

How do i pass selected radio button value to my controller ?

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="data.group1">                  

    <md-radio-button  value="auto" class="md-primary" 
                      ng-click="uploadTemplatesCtrl.submitResult(data.group1)">
        Auto classification
    </md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button  value="manual"  > Manual Selection </md-radio-button>

</md-radio-group>
```

My controller is "uploadTemplatesCtrl". when i use {{data.group1}} it gives me a selected value.But unable pass to controller.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the value into a function, as you already have it in `data.group1` variable. You can move `ng-click` on parent element and then in the function called you have the selected value:

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="data.group1" ng-click="submitResult()">                  
    <md-radio-button  value="auto" class="md-primary">Auto classification</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button  value="manual"> Manual Selection </md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

For example:

```
 $scope.submitResult = function() {
     console.log($scope.data.group1);
}
```

Comment: Html and controller code is in different files.do to deal with it ?@Bill P

Comment: you have to use `ng-controller` directive. Check a jsfiddle example: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4f0nkwjv/1/)